# "And now you will/would say that..."

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, tense, modal-verbs, will-would

I was wondering if the first sentence below is an abuse of grammar or if it is, unwittingly, better grammar than the second sentence.
The sentences are

> 1: *And now you **will** say that they are going to see numbers and freak out, and you would obviously be right, but I am just trying to get my point across.*

and

> 2: *And now you **would** say that they are going to see numbers and freak out, and you would obviously be right, but I am just trying to get my point across.*

Which one of the above is better grammar?

Comment: If the only intended difference is that you use ***will*** once in #1, but not at all in #2, the answer is you should *either* use ***will*** consistently, or use ***would*** consistently. Randomly mixing the two usually doesn't work. I have no opinion as to *which* verb form you "should" use, *so long as you stick to one or the other*.

Comment: They are both **fine**. See my answer.

Comment: If the "true" meaning of ***now*** is in fact ***then*** *(**in that case**)*, which imho is extremely likely, you should probably favour ***would***.

Comment: It's not about grammar, it's about intended meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intended meaning**s:

1: And now you **will say** that they are going to see numbers and freak out, and you would obviously be right, but I am just trying to get my point across.

[That suggests I am coaching you to say something at some point in a situation that will occur. For example, answering questions by a board of ethics.]

and

2: And now you **would say** that they are going to see numbers and freak out, and you would obviously be right, but I am just trying to get my point across.

[That suggests that as your coach I'm giving you **a choice** of what to say to that same board of ethics.]

Another similar example:
Tell them you will go tomorrow. [intention]
Tell them you would go tomorrow if they insist.[possibility]